# Double brace initialisation (anonymous inner class) with diamond operator

Tags: java, generics, java-7

I am wondering why the second map declaration (using the diamond operator) does not compile when the first one does. Compilation error:

> error: cannot infer type arguments for HashMap;
>           Map map2 = new HashMap<>() {
>     reason: cannot use '<>' with anonymous inner classes
>     where K,V are type-variables:
>       K extends Object declared in class HashMap
>       V extends Object declared in class HashMap

Code:

```
    Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String, String>() { //compiles fine

        {
            put("abc", "abc");
        }
    };

    Map<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<>() { //does not compile

        {
            put("abc", "abc");
        }
    };
```

**EDIT**
Thanks for your answers - I should have read the compilation error better.
I found the exaplanation in the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9)

> It is a compile-time error if a class instance creation expression declares an anonymous class using the "<>" form for the class's type arguments.

Comment: Where is the *static* initializer referred to in your title?

Comment: @JonSkeet you are right, can't remember how the "double brace" is called...

Comment: The error refers to an `EnumMap`, but you have only `HashMap`s in your code.

Comment: The error message is pretty self-explanatory: you've created an anonymous inner class of `EnumMap`. I presume, it was accidental.

Comment: @JonSkeet The static initializers are right there in the anonymous classes.

Comment: @SteveTaylor I changed the code but not the error message - amended

Comment: Oops - It's an instance initializer, not a static initializer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have a *static* initializer here (the keyword *static* is missing altogether).

Basically you create a new anonymous subclass of `HashMap` and define the instance intializer block here. Btw, this only works since `HashMap` is not final.

Since you'll get an anonymous subclass of `HashMap` the diamond operator doesn't work here, since the subclass would then be compiled as if you wrote `... extends HashMap<Object, Object>` and this clearly isn't compatible to `Map<String, String>`.

Answer (score 5):

Diamond inference doesn't work for instantiating anonymous classes, which is what you're doing here.

Try this:

```
Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<>();

{
    map1.put("abc", "abc");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This feature is part of **Project Coin 2** and will be avalaible in Java 9 coming September 22 of 2016.

It's call `Allowing the diamond syntax with some anonymous class 
constructors`.

[Link.](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/coin-dev/2015-April/003487.html)

Answer (score 1):

Note that you *could* also omit the diamond altogether. However, while this compiles, it's only because it's ignoring the Java generics and leans on the fact that Java is backwards compatible with previous versions.

```
Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap() { //compiles fine
    {
        put("abc", "abc");
    }
};
```

Comment: correct ... since `it's ignoring the Java generics`