# Creating a Map through an anonymous class with the <>

Tags: java, java-7, diamond-operator

In JDK 1.7 I can create a `Collection` lets for e.g. say a `HashMap` like this:

```
private HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
```

With the diamond `<>` at the end.

But if I am creating a map like this:

```
private static final HashMap<String, String> MAP = new HashMap<>() {{
    put("something", "something");
}};
```

On the diamond compiler says that:

```
Cannot use ''<>'' with anonymous inner classes
```

I have to use: `... new HashMap<String, String>() {{....` in order the code to compile.

Why is it so? Why I can create a map and use diamond if I am creating just a new instance but the code doesn't compile if I am creating a map through an anonymous class?

Comment: Interesting find. Curious myself.

Comment: I don't think it is duplicate - this question is asking WHY. The answers to the other question don't really say why Sun made that decision, just that you can't do it.

Comment: @MrSpoon its actually Oracle's decision, not Sun's .. :P

Comment: I thought generics were added way before Oracle took over.

Comment: @MrSpoon true, but Type Inference was introduced in java 7 after oracle bought sun .. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just a guess but when you do

```
new HashMap<>() {{
    put("something", "something");
}};
```

It actually creates a subclass of `HashMap` I don't like this because you dirty up your classes with a bunch of subclasses. I am guessing in this case Java cannot infer what the generic diamond type is because it is being subclassed.

Comment: but I think the question OP is asking is *why* is Java unable to infer it in this case?

Comment: @mattb *It actually creates a subclass of `HashMap`*

Comment: Yep, but as said on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9773733/double-brace-initialisation-anonymous-inner-class-with-diamond-operator it is also because of subclassing. That question doesn't have an answer either to why though.

Comment: @AmirRaminfar Actually the accepted answer for that question does offer a reason to why: "the subclass would then be compiled as if you wrote `... extends HashMap<Object, Object>` and this clearly isn't compatible to `Map<String, String>`."

Comment: @matts that's right I missed that.